# Debugging a Powershell start-process line

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell's standard ISE to develop a script that, among other things, calls `start-process` using a pre-defined filepath. Here is the code:

```
$MSTEST ="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTEST.EXE"
$TESTSETTING="D:\Source\Test\DEV\FIREBIRD\QA\LoadTesting\WebTests\perfvsctlr2.testsettings"
$TESTCONTAINER1="D:\Source\Infinity\DEV\FIREBIRD\QA\LoadTesting\WebTests\Test.AppFx.LoadTesting.Test\LoadTestDefs\Test_Interactive_Peak_Workload.loadtest"
start-process $MSTEST -ArgumentList "/Testsetting: $TESTSETTING /Testcontainer: $TESTCONTAINER1 /resultsfile: $RESULTSFILE"
```

When I pass the variables and then try to manually execute the `start-process` line from the Powershell prompt it simply opens a window and closes it without displaying the error. So far I've used the `-NoNewWindow` argument and tried calling Powershell from the Run line with the `-noexit` argument. So far, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is $RESULTSFILE defined?

You shouldn't have a space after the colon (and you generally have to look out for spaces in any of your arguments. You don't seem to have any, but spaces in arguments require proper quoting).

You can get the error message from Start-Process by calling it with some extra arguments (the line below produces an error on purpose):

Start-Process $MSTEST -ArgumentList "\testcontainer: file" -wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError err -RedirectStandardOutput out